# Have I been able to successful remove outliers from the dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

I am pretty new to data analytics/ science, my task was to remove outliers from uber.csv, but I am unable to know for sure if I could do so. I know I ask dumb questions on this platform. But please help me.

```
df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df['fare_amount'])) < 3)]
```

This is the code I used
[Before outlier removal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZKi6.png)

[After outlier removal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NBTh.png)

Comment: What is your criteria for outliers?